# How can I estimate the growth models' parameters in nonlinear mixed-effects models using Logistic and Gompertz functions for each ID as x=Age & y=Wt?

Tags: r, parameters, lme4, mixed-models, nlme

How can I estimate the growth models' parameters (by nlme package) of Logistic and Gompertz functions for each ID as x=Age & y=Weight? And how can I add the three covariates (Country, Sex, & Area)?

Dear all,
I have a data set like this in Excel format;

```
ID          Country     Age Weight   Sex    Area
ET010001    Ethiopia    1   8.5     Female  Urban
ET010001    Ethiopia    5   15.6    Female  Urban
ET010001    Ethiopia    8   20.1    Female  Urban
IN010001    India       1   7.6     Male    Urban
IN010001    India       5   16.7    Male    Urban
IN010001    India       8   22.3    Male    Urban
.   .   .   .   .   .
IN200105    India       1   9.5     Male    Urban
IN200105    India       5   17.7    Male    Urban
IN200105    India       8   20.2    Male    Urban
```

How can I estimate the growth models' parameters (by nlme package) of Logistic and Gompertz functions for each ID as x=Age & y=Weight? And how can I add the three covariates (Country, Sex, & Area)?

Thank You!

I expect the solutions from experts in Statistics and r.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  What have you tried so far?  You can use the `fixed=` argument to specify covariates.  The logistic and gompertz functions are available as `SSlogis` and `SSgompertz`: see the corresponding help pages ...  Could we have a [mcve] please?